# not clearing localstorage when you call clear() and then set some localstorage value in same function

Tags: javascript

> having some data in localStorage, in my function first clearing the
>   localstorage using clear() method and then adding one value to
>   the localstorage. But its not clearing the old data

```
function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem('test', 'test');
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/9ob41ts8/), please post a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

Do you call your function or should it be a self executing function?

Self executing example:

```js
(function(){
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem('test', 'test');
})();
```

or as a arrow function (es6)

```js
(() => {
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem('test', 'test');
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can call the function or you can use self-invoking function

```
(function () {
  localStorage.clear();
  localStorage.setItem('test', 'test');
})();
```